# Как вывести содержимое div'а из одного документа в другой?

Tags: html

Как вывести содержимое div'а из одного документа в другой? Например есть один документ, в нем написано следующее:

```
<div id="bla bla">(Содержимое)</div>.
```

А мне нужно в другом документе вывести содержимое div'а. Как это можно сделать в html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно с помощью  PHP

```
<div id="divTag">
<?php  
  include "inner.html"; 
?> 
</div>
```

inner.html
Содержимое

Answer (score 2):

На чистом html только с использованием iframe:

Document1.html:

```
<div id="divTag"><iframe src="inner.html" frameborder="0" style="border:0px;width:100%;"></iframe></div>
```

Document2.html:

```
<div id="divTag"><iframe src="inner.html" frameborder="0" style="border:0px;width:100%;"></iframe></div>
```

inner.html:

```
Содержимое, которое будет в doc1 и в doc2
```

Answer (score 0):

А можно так: при помощи jQuery.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

Тут подробно: [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).